# IDE for Scientific computing using Fortran

Tags: fortran

I am looking to learn Fortran for Scientific Computing, which IDE setup for this exists that supports debugging, code completion capabilities and offers granular Running time Analytics. I am interested in a free software that accomplishes the above requirements and is available on Mac.

Comment: I use a combination of sublime text and the gcc tool-chain on the mac.  The former is kind of free but does provide some code completion.  The latter is ok but takes a bit of patience to do what you are proposing as most of the tool-chain is focused on C and what Fortran support there is can be difficult to work with.  If you are willing to spend money totalview is one of the most complete solutions to the debugging and run-time analytics for Fortran available.  If you are a student I believe it is free.

Comment: @KyleMandli Thanks for your comment. Are you aware of any free software solutions that do running time analysis given that one is not a student?

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! This is way too subjective (and close to off-topic -- there's http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). If you edit your question to focus on the analytics (the rest is too much a matter of personal preference -- you don't want a vi vs. emacs war in the comments) and list exactly what your requirements are, the question could work here, though.

Comment: @ChristianClason Given that Fortran is one of the staple languages in the area of Computational Science, it is pertinent if not necessary to understand the best setup of the same that satisfies three commonly accepted features that a computational scientist would look for, those are the ones listed in the question description. this establishes the necessity of posting this question in SciComp.SE over softwarerecs. In light of this, i think it is entirely appropriate. Additionally, saying that a fight over IDE preferences may occur i feel is an inadequate reason to hold the question.

Comment: @ChristianClason, the only subjective factor in the description was the usage of the epithet 'intuitive' before debugging. I believe now it makes the requirements assessable fairly objectively.

Comment: @anuvaramban I think the 'best' qualifier in your title and question statement, which probably isn't needed, admits there is a spectrum of opinion on this.

Comment: @SpencerBryngelson, question has been edited to remove possibility of Trolls and Pedants from being triggered.

Comment: I have adhered to all the suggested edits to make this question as objective. Please reopen the question

Comment: No responses from Moderators or Experienced Users. Please read the comment thread and question description now and reopen the question if there are no objections. Thank you.